# FA 3.2.1 + Bootstrap 3? Does this work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am working within a secure network and only have access to Bootstrap 3.1 and Font Awesome 3.2.1. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with getting FA to show fonts (Chrome, FireFox, IE). ChromeDevTools show no errors. After some researching, it seems that the culprit is FA 3.2.1 may not be compatible with the new Bootstrap 3 code.

Does anyone know if FA3.2.1 works fine with Bootstrap 3?

Comment: AFAIK, they're compatible. Have you tried to use FA without Bootstrap, to see whether your copy of FA works at all?

Comment: @cvrebert thanks for your comment. I have tested it at home and it works fine, but at work it does not. I'll keep troubleshooting.